# Maven-2: How to manage where the dependency depends on?

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-dependency-plugin

I know, by default, with maven dependencies, it will grab everything it needs from the local repo (.m2 directory). In my application, I don't want it to depend from the local directory, but from a specific location. I've used the `<scope>system</scope>` with `<systemPath>../path/to/file/</systemPath>`, but it still depends from the .m2 directory. Is there anyway I can change where the maven dependencies depend from?

With my application, I'm using the native code (C++) and there are `.nar` and `.so` files. In this example, I specifically need to depend on a `.so` file in a specific directory, but it's always going to the .m2 directory. Is there a plugin that could fix this?

Also, to note that I'm using Maven 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

First there is nothing to fix in Maven. Maven is working that way. In your case you need an artifact which is not within a maven repository that means you need to transfer that file into a maven repository and afterwards you can use simply dependencies to use that file (.so). There are two possible solutions:

Using the [install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/) to install that particular file into your local repository as an artifact by giving groupId, artifactId and version

mvn install:install-file ...

The other and best solution is to use a [repository manager](http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html) and install the needed files into the repository manager which makes it possible being used by other people as well and not only by you.

Comment: There's no way to overwrite the dependency directory from the local repo to a custom path?

Comment: @Rob, there is a way to set the repo directory, but maven will simply download all the dependencies into that new location. If you have a dependency that is not normally available through maven central, you typically either install it manually as described, or give it system scope and specify the path to it.